# Import PATH variable into systemd unit

Tags: systemd

I have a systemd service that looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Kcrypt Backend Webpack Bundler
After=network.target

[Service]
User=kenny
Environment=NODE_ENV=PROD
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/kcrypt-api/
ExecStart=/var/www/kcrypt-api/scripts/webpack.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The .sh file looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export NODE_ENV=DEV

rm ./dist/* -rf

yarn start webpack --watch
```

The problem is that it cannot find `yarn`.

My user is called `kenny`. `kenny` has a tool called `nvm` installed that manages `nodejs` versions. That tool adds a directory to the `PATH` env variable by editing '~/.bashrc'.

That means that the `yarn` command is only available if the user is logged in as `kenny`.

I was left with the impression that if I set the `systemd`'s `unit`'s user to 'kenny', `systemd` will take care of the rest, or I don't know what I was thinking.

Is there any way that I can import `kenny`'s PATH variable into the `systemd` `unit`?

Comment: You should not be calling that script at all. You should call yarn directly from the systemd unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to 'reference a user's `PATH` variable', you should either define `PATH` manually, or more appropriately, use the full path to the binary.

> That means that the yarn command is only available if the user is logged in as kenny

This isn't accurate. It just means that `yarn` isn't installed in a location referenced by the `PATH` variable used by systemd, and is likely in a custom location, or location outside of the default PATH variable.

When you're logged in as `kenny`, use `which yarn` to print the path to `yarn`, then make sure to use that when referencing it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

bash will only source `~/.bashrc` if you're running it as an interactive shell, it won't do that if you're simply running bash for a script.

Considering systemd is only running bash as the interpreter of the `webpack.sh` script (in fact, it doesn't even know that bash is involved, the kernel executes it as the interpreter from the #! line), then it's not an interactive shell, and no startup files are read.

You can work around that by sourcing `~/.bashrc` explicitly at the start of your `webpack.sh` script, assuming everything in there is safe to run in a non-interactive shell. (It should be fine.)

So consider adding this line to the start of your script:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```